# Can i be forgiven if i commited this major act?

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness, masturbation, pornography

Salam i have been Watching porn knowingly it is wronge but i just can not stop the urge when it comes and i sometimes have masturbated to it as well but now i have left it and want to change i have realized this sin please tell me will Allah forgive me for both the sins if i am genuine in my seekness of forgiveness and not repeat that sin again i can not feel motivation anymore i have been doing this since monthe and can jot talk to anyone about this in my family and want to change so please my brothers and sisters am i still forgivable

Answer (score 0):

Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said,

> “If your sins were to reach to the heavens and then you repented,
> Allah would still accept your repentance.” 
> **Source: Sunan Ibn Mājah 4248** 
> **Grade: Sahih according to Al-Albani**

Allah will forgive you.

Comment: Thank you brother sister